# Echo SSH key into the container messes docker build output

Tags: docker, ssh

I need to use SSH keys inside a container during build stage and I do that with

```
RUN echo "${SSH_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Where SSH_KEY is build arg. The problem is, once this command is done, the output is messed up:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile          0.0s
[+] Building 733.0s (21/22)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile          0.0s
[+] Building 733.2s (21/22)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile          0.0s
[+] Building 733.3s (21/22)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile          0.0s
[+] Building 733.5s (21/22)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile          0.0s
[+] Building 733.6s (21/22)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile          0.0s
[+] Building 733.6s (22/22) FINISHED
```

Above is printed repeatedly until the build is done. Is there anything I can do about that?

Otherwise, the container building works fine.

Comment: Is there any functional change (does the image still build successfully), or is just the cosmetic buildkit output?  Doing this compromises your private key (anyone with the image can trivially extract it); do you _really_ want to do this?

Comment: To build-up on the above comment: you are apparently using buildkit. Why don't you take advantage of the [new available feature to share ssh keys from host during build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds)?

Comment: @DavidMaze this is never leaves our infra so that's OK imo. Also, I am using multi-stage build so --correct me if I'm wrong-- it's not easily extractable with multi-stage builds? The duplicated messages are just a cosmetic issue. Build works fine.

Comment: @Zeitounator nice. I was not aware of that. I'll definitely check that.

Comment: `his is never leaves our infra so that's OK imo` <= this is always ok until it leaves your infra when it was not supposed to or someone gains access to you infra when he was not supposed to. There is only one good answer to David's rhetoric question: **you don't want to do that!**

Comment: @Zeitounator adding ```--mount=type=ssh``` to Dockerfile's RUN git clone command and then using ```--ssh default``` with docker run command does not seem to work for me. How do I know if it's available with my image? Docs say that there is some syntax requirement as well ```# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1```

Comment: @Zeitounator ok, figured this out. I forgot to run ```ssh-add``` beforehand, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenters suggested, using `--mount=type=ssh` flag for `RUN git clone` lines works a lot better.